# Extremely low FPS in all the games

Tags: pc, technical-issues, counter-strike-global-offensive, graphics-card

I used to play games on my system like GTA IV, Mafia II and Counter Strike : Global Offensive around 1.5 years ago and then I quit gaming.
Then after a few months, I tried playing those games again, but I started getting low FPS. 
Thinking of this as some software issue, I did not wanted to re-install Windows or reset my PC. I just re-installed my Graphics drivers (which failed to solve the issue).

So, today I did a full hard drive format, re-installed Windows and was shocked to see that I am still getting low FPS.

Any solutions?

```
System Information:
 1. Windows 10 (64-bit)
 2. Intel® Core™ i5-3337U Processor (3M Cache, up to 2.70 GHz)
 3. AMD Radeon(TM) HD 8730M with 2G DDR3 VRAM
 4. 4GB 1 DIMM (4GB x1) DDR3 1600Mhz

Reference FPS:
 1. Counter-Strike : Global Offensive
 2. Extremely Low Settings (Anti-Aliasing turned off, all details to very low, minimal resolution)
 3. Less than 20 FPS
```

Comment: If your computer is playing games slower than it used to and you did a complete wipe and reinstall then my guess is that problem is overheating.

Comment: Another factor may be software you have running in the background while trying to play games.

Comment: @MadMAxJr Nothing is running in the background. Wiped Hard Drive, Installed Windows, Installed Radeon Drivers and launched the game.

Comment: @RossRidge Temperature seems completely normal.

Comment: does your laptop have some kind of power management/performance options? sometimes the laptop can be put into "powersave" mode which throttles gpu/cpu/ram

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer My laptop is on High Performance mode and the Radeon settings are also on Optimize Performance. :(

Comment: and you are absolutely positive that the radeon card is the one being utilized and not the iGPU from the intel chip? i believe you can check with gpu-z

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer GPU-Z lists both of them.

Comment: I would recommend to find some software that lets you monitor the temps + clock frequencies, and then also download a benchmark like Unigine Valley and run in it on low/medium settings in a window and watch the monitor to see which gpu is being utilized and whether the clocks go up to the manufacturer listed max (8730M should be around 650mhz gpu/ 2000mhz memory) if the clocks aren't being hit then there must be something wrong with the card, if it hits max clocks then try your game again, but keep the monitoring software running, check the monitor after testing out the game for a bit

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer Checked using GPU-Z, it went till 700 MHz GPU core clock and 900 MHz GPU Memory clock under 99% load.

Comment: Are your graphics drivers up to date? Suddenly my games started to go bad and simply updating Radeon Crimson solved it.

Comment: Yes, they are up to date. Downloaded and installed just now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Issue resolved. The problem was with the charger, it was not giving the rated output.

## **Learning**

> If drivers and a hard reset do not fix the problem, temperatures are
>   normal, clock speed is not limited but *utilization is less*, power
>   supply could be a problem.

Since I was in a hurry, I asked a question which does not belongs to this site, here is the question which is more descriptive and is where it belongs :)

https://superuser.com/questions/1063578/low-frame-rate-in-every-game-with-capable-enough-hardware/1064352#1064352